# Turn list of lists into specific length in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

How can I create a list of 3 lists with specific length 20,30,40 to get last 20 vectors of data as list1, last 30 vectors of data as list2, last 40 vectors of data as list3

turn

```
data <- seq(1,100,1)
length.y <- c(20,30,40)
```

into

```
y[[1]]=seq(81,100,1)
y[[2]]=seq(71,100,1)
y[[3]]=seq(61,100,1)
```

I can use a for loop or create a function like this

```
y <- rep(list(0),3)
for(i in 1:3){
    y[[i]] <- data[(length(data)-length.y[i]+1):length(data)]
}
```

My data is way complicate then this, so
is there an easier way to get the same result? (using lapply for example)

Comment: This does it `lapply(length.y, function(x) tail(data, x))`.

Comment: And squish it if you want - `lapply(length.y, tail, x=data)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `tail` as already suggested in comments is an easy way. You can also turn your `for` loop code to `lapply` as :

```
n <- length(data)
lapply(length.y, function(x) data[(n-x + 1):n])

#[[1]]
# [1]  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98
#[19]  99 100

#[[2]]
# [1]  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88
#[19]  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

#[[3]]
# [1]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78
#[19]  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
#[37]  97  98  99 100
```

Answer (score 0):

using `purrr::map`

```
map(length.y, ~ data[-c(1:(length(data) - .x))])

[[1]]
 [1]  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

[[2]]
 [1]  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

[[3]]
 [1]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94
[35]  95  96  97  98  99 100
```